# What do I need to do to fly a Microlight to France?

Tags: easa-regulations, ultralight, uk, france

I wish to fly a C42 to France from the UK. I can file the flight plan from Skydemon, but I have an NPPL, so I believe I need to obtain permission from French authorities and maybe do other things.

Please could someone tell me what to do and ideally provide links to any online forms etc.

many thanks

Comment: Suspect all the info is here: https://www.bmaa.org/flying-abroad

Comment: Going the other direction, I read somewhere that Bleriot wasn't allowed to disembark until a British official clambered aboard and declared that his contraption wasn't a plague ship.